# Expected agreement if random

Tags: expected-value, agreement-statistics

I am looking to measure agreement between participants in choosing which member of a group is most like certain attributes. I want to calculate the expected agreement if they were to choose by chance.
e.g. assume we have 3 participants (P1, P2, P3) and they can choose from a list of 3 people (A,B,C) to associate with a characteristic (Cx). The results could be:

```
characteristic   P1   P2   P3
C1               A    B    A
C2               C    B    B
C3               A    A    A
...
```

If, in this case, the agreement is an average of P1vP2, P1vP3, and P2vP3 and agreement was {0,1} then we would have:

```
C1  1/3
C2  1/3
C3  3/3
```

How could I calculate the expected agreement if the choices were made at random?

Comment: You have chosen an interesting way to index agreement. Do you see an advantage of your approach over percent choosing A, B, or C for each Cx?  Will the two approaches always yield the same findings?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. However, that will result in three percentages. If I want to extend this to more than {A,B,C} then the number of measures will increase. What I'm interested in is a measure for each Cx or a measure for each set of participants (which may end up as more than 3).